# How to fix gcc include path search order problem (input/output error)?

Tags: gcc, gcc5

One of our Ubuntu 16.04 systems (gcc 5.4.0) is failing a compilation that previously succeeded.  The failure is:

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -m64 -march=native -I../Kernel -I/net/simdata/Hudson_OpenSourceLibs/Boost/ -fpic -O3 
../StarLibs/StdStars/ArithmeticCoding.cpp -o _gnuRelease/ArithmeticCoding.o
cc1plus: fatal error:
/net/simdata/Hudson_OpenSourceLibs/Boost/stdc-predef.h: Input/output error 
compilation terminated.
```

If I exclude the  -I/net/simdata ... (which is a mounted drive) the compilation succeeds without failure.

For the failure case, the search order is:

```
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 ../Kernel
 /net/simdata/Hudson_OpenSourceLibs/Boost/
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

(shown by adding -v to the gcc command).

The include file in question is not on the mounted drive but is found (as expected) at:

```
$ ls /usr/include/stdc-predef.h
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h
```

The mount seems to be working ok:

```
$ ls /net/simdata/Hudson_OpenSourceLibs/Boost/rel-1.69.0/boost/
accumulators     dll.hpp   make_unique.hpp  random.hpp
align    dynamic_bitset   math    range
etc.
```

I don't understand why gcc is reporting an i/o failure for the mounted drive and is failing to find the include file in /usr/include.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Looks like it is not linked to gcc but to the drive or to the mouting. May be the driver is almost full ?